# Some of deleted branchs shown in local config file as a section

Tags: git

In my local config file (which is under {local_repo_directory}.git there are some branches, which are not exists in local and remote repo (like: FIX-RD01). 
I deleted one branch with `git config --local --remove-section branch.Rf-FixWarning`command but as i understand doing this only remove the section which contains below lines:

```
[branch "FIX-RD01"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/FIX-RD01
```

I want to ask if it is safety to delete non existence branches from config file manually with an editor or above command. Why some of deleted braches shown in this file. How should i act, for these sections (in local config file).

Local config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@bitbucket.aaa.com:1234/abc/abc.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "FIX-RD01"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/FIX-RD01
[gui]
    wmstate = zoomed
    geometry = 893x435+52+52 175 196
```

Comment: Deleting obsolete entries from git config files is pretty safe.

Comment: Although there is not my existing/active branches, why local config file contains some of deleted branches.

Comment: Probably you should perform some experiments creating and and then deleting branches, and if the effect (not deleting branch entry in the config after the branch is deleted with `git branch -D <branchname>`) is reproducible on the latest git version, then you should file a bug as @torek suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have a branch named `FIX-RD01`, there *should not* be a config section named `[branch "FIX-RD01"]`.  It is safe to delete it, but you should not have to, because whatever deleted the branch should have also deleted the config section.

If you can identify whatever process it is that you are employing that deletes a branch name without also deleting its configuration section, you will have found a bug.  (Well, that is, unless you're invoking `git update-ref -d` directly yourself, or removing files from within `.git` or editing `.git/packed-refs` yourself, and so on.)

Comment: I use SourceTree and GitKraken as a git client. Especially SourceTree uses so much parameters event in the simplest opreations. So i do not know what may cause this. And also AntiVirus program may cause this problem. If i can discover a reproducible scenario, i will report as a bug. Thank you.